# How to allow org-babel to play with python virtual environment?

Tags: org-mode, python, org-babel

I have virtual environment set on my system (actually [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)). I would like to direct org babel to use a specific environment in a single code block or on the whole buffer. How can I do it?

Answer (score 6):

I believe I found the solution.

1. Install [virtualenvwrapper](https://github.com/porterjamesj/virtualenvwrapper.el)
2. Run the setup:

   ```
   (require 'virtualenvwrapper)
   (venv-initialize-interactive-shells) ;; if you want interactive shell support
   (venv-initialize-eshell) ;; if you want eshell support
   (setq venv-location "/path/to/your/virtualenvs/")
   ```
3. Finally, `workon` the desired virtual environment. Then you can run code block and use the desired interpreter.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this with us. Would be useful as future reference, when someone stumbles upon same issue.

Comment: For future reference, this only works for me if I use a :session